# Merge pdf files and loss of information

Tags: java, pdf, itext, accessibility, pdfbox

doing the merge of 2 or + pdf I lose some information that imposed in the upload phase of the files (ALT tags on the images). This is the method:

```
public static void mergeFiles(ArrayList<String> filesToBeMerged, String mergedFileLocation) {   

    String[] filesTBM = filesToBeMerged.toArray(new String[filesToBeMerged.size()]);
    PDFMergerUtility ut = new PDFMergerUtility();
        try {       
          for (int i = 0; i < filesTBM.length; i++) {
                ut.addSource(filesTBM[i]);               
              }
          ut.setDestinationFileName(mergedFileLocation);
          ut.mergeDocuments();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (COSVisitorException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

If the PDF with the ALT tags were in the list of files to be merged, the result is correct, otherwise not. So far I've tried max with 3 PDFs including 1 with ALT tags.
The questions:

How can I not lose the alt tag after the merge of the files?
Thanks to those who want to help me
Daniele

N.b. I have also tried iText pdf:

```
  public static void mergeFiles(ArrayList<String> filesToBeMerged, String mergedFileLocation) {
```

String[] filesTBM = filesToBeMerged.toArray(new String[filesToBeMerged.size()]);

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = null;
    try {
        copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(mergedFileLocation));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    document.open();
    PdfReader[] reader = new PdfReader[filesTBM.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < filesTBM.length; i++) {
        try {
            reader[i] = new PdfReader(filesTBM[i]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            copy.addDocument(reader[i]);
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            copy.freeReader(reader[i]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        reader[i].close();
    }
    document.close(); 
}
```

Comment: You don't show the code of the `mergeDocuments()` method. Chances are that the method is completely wrong. I have been fighting against *wrong examples* on unofficial web sites for many years, but people still keep doing it wrong because they don't look at the examples on the [official web site](http://itextpdf.com). Your code also doesn't show whether you're using iText 5 (if so, stop doing so) or iText 7 (the latest version; the version you should use). If you claim that `mergeDocuments()` is an iText method: it isn't (look at my name, and you'll know you can believe me).

Comment: what is the question - can you emphasize please

Comment: TKs Bruno, i'm using the library pdfbox

Comment: Hi xhudik, excuse me i add the questions: How can I not lose the alt tag after the merge of the files?

Comment: *"i'm using the library pdfbox"* - then why is your question tagged [tag:itext] and not [tag:pdfbox]?

Comment: because i'm tryng itext too:

Comment: Ok, at least you added the [tag:pdfbox] tag. Perhaps @Tilman can answer this.

Comment: Please use PDFBox 2.0.8 and not an 1.8.* version and link to PDFs that show the problem. I don't know about ALT-tags, but if these are part of the structure tree, then I have bad news: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4007

Comment: PDFBox 2.0.8 return same result: entry pdf with tags alt + pdf only text = merge pdf without tags alt on images

Comment: another solution (library)?

Comment: Try iText 7! It's a complete rewrite of the old iText version you were using.